# Is it possible to get a UNIX timestamp from Tizen Web API?

Tags: tizen-web-app

Looking at the Time API documentation, I don't see this capability, but maybe it is present in part of the Web API. I didn't find anything in the Dev Guide. I could create one myself using UTC time, but it seems like the system should provide this.

Comment: What Tizen SDK version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

You can use the standard JavaScript Date object.

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
```

In the time var you will have a timestamp value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use Tizen Native Code for that. E.g.

```
void sensor_event_callback(sensor_event_s *event) {
    char *timestamp = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
    sprintf(timestamp, "%lld", event->timestamp);
    free(timestamp);
}
```